# Removing one of multiple resources - Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

Im having the following issue with the Google Calendar API. I have a meeting that's in two rooms and i want to remove one of the rooms. So i'm sending over an event update with the attendees changed. Before the attendees were the organiser and two rooms and now they are the organiser and one room. When i send this the meeting is removed from both rooms, but remains on the users calendar.

I've tried sending the data with both rooms to see if maybe the attendee is missing some information but this keeps both rooms.

```
$response = $calendarService->events->update(
    'primary',
    $event->getId(),
    $event
);
```

This is my event:

```
{
    "anyoneCanAddSelf": null,
    "attendeesOmitted": null,
    "colorId": null,
    "created": null,
    "description": null,
    "endTimeUnspecified": null,
    "etag": null,
    "eventType": null,
    "guestsCanInviteOthers": null,
    "guestsCanModify": null,
    "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": null,
    "hangoutLink": null,
    "htmlLink": null,
    "iCalUID": null,
    "id": "7d3kjpat0j885820khh40plk4f",
    "kind": null,
    "location": null,
    "locked": null,
    "privateCopy": null,
    "recurrence": null,
    "recurringEventId": null,
    "sequence": null,
    "status": null,
    "summary": "test",
    "transparency": null,
    "updated": null,
    "visibility": "default",
    "start": {
        "date": null,
        "dateTime": "2023-09-20T03:45:00-07:00",
        "timeZone": null
    },
    "end": {
        "date": null,
        "dateTime": "2023-09-20T04:30:00-07:00",
        "timeZone": null
    },
    "attendees": {
        "0": {
            "additionalGuests": null,
            "comment": null,
            "displayName": null,
            "email": "myRoom@resource.calendar.google.com",
            "id": null,
            "optional": true,
            "organizer": null,
            "resource": true,
            "responseStatus": null,
            "self": null
        },
        "2": {
            "additionalGuests": null,
            "comment": null,
            "displayName": null,
            "email": "me@email.com",
            "id": null,
            "optional": true,
            "organizer": null,
            "resource": null,
            "responseStatus": null,
            "self": null
        }
    }
}
```